# Обработка любой ошибки при вызове метода

Tags: php

В коде вызывается некоторые метод, someClass::getSomeMethod();

В процессе работы метода, могут возникнуть любые ошибки, в т.ч. и фатальные.
Например вызов несуществующего метода и т.д.

Каким образом можно при возникновении ошибки, продолжить выполнять скрипт дальше?

Например

```
# тут много кода
someClass::getSomeMethod(); # этот метод - в свою очередь дергает кучу других методов разных классов, где нет гарантии что не может возникнуть ошибка.
# и дальше много кода
```

При возникновении ошибку где то в методе someClass::getSomeMethod(); нужно штатно продолжить выполнять дальше код.

Пробовал так

```
# тут много кода
    try {
        someClass::getSomeMethod();
    } catch (Exception $e) {

    }
# и дальше много кода
```

Но все равно возникает фатальная ошибку, которую я умышленно допустил в вложенных класса.

Comment: не уверен, но возможно это поможет решить вашу проблему `@someClass::getSomeMethod();`

Comment: @AntonKucenko прекрасный способ, ящетаю. Надо распространить и на другие сферы.  Если человек умер, то надо просто никому об этом не говорить. И он будет всё равно что живой!

Comment: Такого результата добиться можно, но это отличный способ выстрелить себе в ногу. И без качественного объяснения, зачем такое может понадобиться (а я подозреваю банальную лень, как единственную причину) я настоятельно не рекомендую двигаться этим путем

Comment: В 7 php появилась возможность отлавливать ошибки синтаксиса. Данное исключение не унаследовано от Exception и его нужно перехватывать отдельно https://wiki.php.net/rfc/engine_exceptions_for_php7